# Get the directory path of absolute file path in Python

Tags: python, path

I want to get the directory where the file resides. For example the full path is:

```
fullpath = "/absolute/path/to/file"
# something like:
os.getdir(fullpath) # if this existed and behaved like I wanted, it would return "/absolute/path/to"
```

I could do it like this:

```
dir = '/'.join(fullpath.split('/')[:-1])
```

But the example above relies on specific directory separator and is not really pretty. Is there a better way?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> fullpath = '/absolute/path/to/file'
>>> os.path.dirname(fullpath)
'/absolute/path/to'
```

Related functions:

```
>>> os.path.basename(fullpath)
'file'
>>> os.path.split(fullpath)
('/absolute/path/to','file')
```

Comment: Why do you `import os.path` instead of simply `import os`?

Comment: I used to think that importing `os.path` won't allow me to import `os.anything_else` (i.e. I need to `import os`). Found myself wrong when I tried it.